# Execution time and big O

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, analysis, execution

(Before anyone says anything Yes this was homework but i have already turned it in and have gotten it back, i just want to figure this out for the test tomorrow.)

The problem was to calculate the execution times and big O for the code snippet. I can calculate the big O fine, but i dont get how you can determine the execution time. Ok basically what i dont understand is how to calculate the execution time

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    SomeJavaStatment;
    for(j=0; j < 2 * n; J+= 2){ 
        SomeJavaStatment;
        SomeJavaStatment;
}
}
```

the correct answer was Big O(n^2) I got that right however I had no idea what the execution time was, and the correct answer for that was 4n^2+5n+2.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how i would go about getting to that answer.

Comment: I fear your prof is using "execution time" in some rather peculiar manner. You'll have to look up the definition for that one yourself, I doubt it's standard terminology..

Comment: I think it's abstracted. Consider n some multiple of seconds, and then you can convert the formula into 'time.' This would, of course, depend on the clock speed of the machine where the code is executing.

Comment: It's way too abstract, `SomeJavaStatement` could be much more complex than `i++`

Comment: Agreed. To make sense it should define SomeJavaStatement as an operation of O(1). There was probably some definition left out of the question here for brevity's sake.

Comment: @ingyhere Even then, that has absolutely nothing to do with the execution time (add is a good bit cheaper than mul on most CPUs), but just the number of statements. Ah well

Comment: @Voo SomeJavaStatement is singular, meaning one operation. I don't think it refers to a method call. ... But I get what you're saying.

Comment: @ingyhere Well `statement` is an exactly defined token in the JLS and even more general `statement` is quite usual in grammars and has a specific meaning (you can look it up in $18 of the JLS). `{foo(); bar(); baz();}` is a single statement for example. Apart from that  the simple fact is, that `mul eax, ebx` is about 3times as expensive as `add eax, ebx` on modern x86 CPUs. Hence such generalizations are completely useless anyhow. If I were the student I'd go complain (ok no, I wouldn't - lazyness and all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think, that execution time should be determined that way but:

```
 //assignment to i takes 1 operation    
 for(i=0; i < n; i++){ // i++ is executed n times, i < n is executed (n+1) times
    SomeJavaStatment; // n times

    //assignment to j takes 1 operation
    for(j=0; j < 2 * n; j+= 2){  // j+=2 is executed n*n times, j < 2*n is executed n*(n+1) times
        SomeJavaStatment; // n * n times
        SomeJavaStatment; // n * n times
    }
 }
```

In total it gives 1 + n + (n+1) + n + n + (n*n) + (n+1)*n + (n*n) + (n*n) = `4 * n^2 + 5*n + 2` :)

Comment: You're talking about the variable 'i' in the comment next to 'j' looping.

Answer (score 0):

Big O describes the upper bound of a function. Your function is not only Big O(n^2), but it also has tight bounds (for any given value of `n`, the function has the exact same runtime). You can manually calculate the *exact* tight bound, or you can express it as a summation resulting in `4n^2+5n+2`.